# How to group the columns based on Month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to group the columns based on the month using pandas pivot table or group-by

I have tried many formats of pivot table, but that doesn't help

```
data_frame4 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame4, index=['PC'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Bill3'], columns=['Month'], margins=True, fill_value=0)
```

my input(data_frame4):

```
PC  Month   Bill1   Bill2   Bill3
A   Feb-19    1       1        1
A   April-19  1       1         1
B   Feb-19     1      1         1
B   April-19   1      1         1
C   Feb-19     1      1         1
C   April-19   1      1         1
```

my code output:

```
           Bill1           Bill2       Bill3        
Month   Apr-19  Feb-19  Apr-19  Feb-19  Apr-19  Feb-19  
PC  
A          1       1    1       1          1    1   
B          1       1    1       1          1    1   
C          1       1    1       1          1    1
```

my desired Output:

```
           Feb-19                Apr-19     
PC  Bill1   Bill2   Bill3   Bill1   Bill2   Bill3
A         1     1    1       1       1       1
B         1     1    1       1       1       1
C         1     1    1       1       1       1
```

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the answer. but the months are not in order.
they need to be in order.

Comment: my output is displaying as Month --- Aug-19----- Apr-19
but i need the output as Month ----Jan-19----Feb-19---and so on
i believe it is sorting alphabetically

Comment: @jezrael pls help me out

Comment: @jezrael only 2019 year but in the future i will be using 2020 as well..
hence i need to sort them based on months from jan to dec..
also the months are in date format and not in string

Comment: @jezrael i dont get it.. could u please explain again...
i am new to python ...so please be descriptive ..Thanxx :)

Comment: your sample data are mess - not idea what need in expcted output, because not matched input vs output dataframe

Comment: @jezrael  ... is the sample data fine now?

Comment: super, can you explain `also the months are in date format and not in string` ?

Comment: @jezrael the month column is in date format

Comment: hmmm, I cannot see it...

Comment: @jezrael
 data_frame['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['Month'])
    data_frame['Month'] = data_frame['Month'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))
i have converted it to the month format before passing it to another dataframe

Comment: is possible omit `data_frame['Month'] = data_frame['Month'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y'))` ?

Comment: @jezrael ..
bro my facebook name is "Praveen Snowy"... could you please add me.. i can explain you in a chat....i really need your help  :(

Comment: @jezrael..i am consolidating data from 3 excel files...
first dataframe has column month(as number) and year..
so i have made them as single column named as Month(example (8-2019))
hence i have used the code
data_frame['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame['Month']) ......data_frame['Month'] = data_frame['Month'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b-%y')

Comment: @jezrael ....im getting the below error when using the pivot table code.........

DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: All............
please help me out

Comment: @jezrael bro i used the code .....pd.pivot_table(data_frame4, index=['Parent Customer'], values=['Billed FTE1', 'CF Value', 'Total Net Revenue'], columns=['Month'], margins=True), but im getting the error as ..
DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: All

Comment: @jezrael bro im getting error as OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-08-19 00:00:00

Comment: @jezrael... i have found the problem...it is with the column named "ALL" which is next to Bill1, Bill2, Bill3
y is it showing up in the table?.. is it possible to remove the "All"...i think the code will work if that column doesn't show up

Comment: So remove `margins=True` in `data_frame4 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame4, index=['PC'], values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Bill3'], columns=['Month'], margins=True, fill_value=0)`

Comment: @jezrael bro the code worked when i replaced ...........
data_frame4['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame4['Month']).dt.to_period('m') ......into......data_frame4['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame4['Month'])....

Comment: @jezrael please help me out whenever i am struck in the future days ...thanks a ton :-) :-)

Comment: @jezrael.. if possible could you please help me understand the code..
tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a != 'All' else (a, b) for a, b in data_frame4.columns]
data_frame4.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)

Comment: It is [`MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) and [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: @jezrael .. how to change a dataframe column which is of type float values (1.22) to currency values ($ 1.22) ...

Comment: Use `df = '% ' + df.round(2).astype(str)`

Comment: @jezrael... i dont want it to be string value because that column(Total Net Revenue) is used for pivot table... if  the column is of type String ..it doesn't show up in the pivot table..
data_frame4 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame4, index=['PC'], values=['Bill1', 'Total Net Revenue'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)

Comment: I think the best post new question, with inpu data, expected output and what you try.

Comment: @jezrael ...how to change the values to currency for the column **Bill3**
which is present under your statement ...**Last swap levels, sorting and then in last step convert to month-year format in list comprehension**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert column to datetimes and months periods:

```
data_frame4['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame4['Month']).dt.to_period('m')
print (data_frame4)
  PC    Month  Bill1  Bill2  Bill3
0  A  2019-02      1      1      1
1  A  2019-04      1      1      1
2  B  2019-02      1      1      1
3  B  2019-04      1      1      1
4  C  2019-02      1      1      1
5  C  2019-04      1      1      1
```

Then use `pivot_table` with month periods (for correct ordering cannot be used  months names):

```
data_frame4 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame4, 
                             index=['PC'], 
                             values=['Bill1', 'Bill2', 'Bill3'], 
                             columns=['Month'], 
                             margins=True, 
                             fill_value=0)
print (data_frame4)
                    Bill1                                       Bill2  \
Month 2019-02-01 00:00:00 2019-04-01 00:00:00 All 2019-02-01 00:00:00   
PC                                                                      
A                       1                   1   1                   1   
B                       1                   1   1                   1   
C                       1                   1   1                   1   
All                     1                   1   1                   1   

                                            Bill3                          
Month 2019-04-01 00:00:00 All 2019-02-01 00:00:00 2019-04-01 00:00:00 All  
PC                                                                         
A                       1   1                   1                   1   1  
B                       1   1                   1                   1   1  
C                       1   1                   1                   1   1  
All                     1   1                   1                   1   1
```

Last swap levels, sorting and then in last step convert to `month-year` format in list comprehension:

```
data_frame4 = data_frame4.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
tuples = [(a.strftime('%b-%y'), b) if a != 'All' else (a, b) for a, b in data_frame4.columns]
data_frame4.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples)
print (data_frame4)
    Feb-19             Apr-19               All            
     Bill1 Bill2 Bill3  Bill1 Bill2 Bill3 Bill1 Bill2 Bill3
PC                                                         
A        1     1     1      1     1     1     1     1     1
B        1     1     1      1     1     1     1     1     1
C        1     1     1      1     1     1     1     1     1
All      1     1     1      1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: im getting the below error when using the pivot table code

DateParseError: Unknown datetime string format, unable to parse: All
please help me out

Comment: could  u please help me out

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - try change `data_frame4['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame4['Month'], format='%b-%y').dt.to_period('m')` to `data_frame4['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data_frame4['Month']).dt.to_period('m')`

Comment: bro im getting error as 
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-08-19 00:00:00

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - Unfortunately still not possible from your side create `my input(data_frame4):` like in real data (there are datetimes, in question not). So not possible help you. sorry.

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - Last friend advice - [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), really check it, please and then change your data for possible solve your problem.